# How to execute exe using python and pass parameter as per the output received from the console

Tags: python-3.x

So far I am able to pass one integer variable after executing an exe. But based on first input passed we have to pass another parameter. Can someone please suggest how to pass the 2nd parameter and so on?

```
import os, subprocess

executable=("xyz.exe")
p = subprocess.Popen(executable, shell=True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(b'4')
```

Comment: `p.communicate(b'4\n5')` does the job?

Comment: Yes that did the job:)

Comment: If it worked, may you accept the answer, please?

Comment: Sure Mate... :)

Comment: thank you @king! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make an example. Your exe is a `c` program like:

```c
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a;
  char path[256];

  scanf("%d", &a);
  scanf("%s", path); 

  FILE *f;
  if (f = fopen(path, "w")) {
    fprintf(f, "%d, %s\n", a, path);
    fclose(f);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

from your python you can invoke it like that:

```
# test.py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

exe = ("./test")
with Popen(exe, shell=True, stdin=PIPE) as proc:
    proc.communicate(b'4\n/tmp/test.txt')
```

to get as result in `/tmp/test.txt`: `4, /tmp/test.txt\n`.

Comment: Great.!! Its working as expected :)

In the 2nd input it is suppose to take input as file path along with the option(like 1,2 or any integer).
@Matteo Ragni
How to achieve that?

Comment: actually nothing changes. check the answer again. Maybe I'll write something more interesting...

Comment: Ok now the path for writing the output file is given by `proc.communicate`.